# Terraform: resolve "no available releases match the given constraints" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to update hashicorp/aws provider version.

I added terraform.tf file with following content:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Later I tried to update modules using:

```
terraform init -upgrade
```

However, I have started to get:

```
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: no available releases match the given constraints >= 2.0.0, ~> 3.27, ~> 4.0
```

How could this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the important part of the error message.

```
>= 2.0.0, ~> 3.27, ~> 4.0
```

1. You request a version greater than or equal to 2.0.0
2. You prefer a version 3.27
3. You prefer a version 4.0

Both 2 and 3 cannot be possible at the same time.

The solution for this specific case is the stop requesting 2 different versions at the same time.

Check versions of available providers:

```
!+?main ~/Projects/x/src/x-devops/terraform/env/test> terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── module.test-sonar
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── module.client_vpn
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── module.test-appserver
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] ~> 3.27
├── module.test-vpn-server
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── module.test-networking
...
```

There is a module which requests `3.27`.

Find all modules which request 3.27 and update them to 4.0.

This should resolve such problems.

Comment: thank you for your explain, i'm facing the same error, and this save my day

Comment: you save my day, thank you for a nice explanation :)